# Visual Studio Report: Checking how many lines are still available on a page

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, reporting

I have a report which has a table to which I keep adding records but there is a certain place I want to check how many lines are still left on the print page and if its below a certain amount I want it to continue on the next page.

Can anyone please tell me how to check the number of lines left and also how to tell the report to start on a new page?

Comment: not sure actually, I know I'm using devExpres's reports